Title: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _c_internal_utils and OSError: [WinError 126] with Matplotlib and PyTorch
I'm encountering an ImportError and OSError when trying to import matplotlib, seaborn and torch in my Jupiter libraries environment. The specific error messages are:
Matplotlib and seaborn Error
Torch Error
I have created the virtual enviroment from conda. The environment was working fine before these installations, and I did not install any new libraries recently. Now, I am encountering the above errors in every script, even simple ones and not in running in virtual environment.
Libraries Installed:
NumPy Version: 1.26.4
Matplotlib Version: (latest version installed but cannot import)
Matplotlib Version
Python Version: 3.12.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Apr 15 2024, 18:20:11) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
flwr Version: 1.10.0
pytorch Version: 1.13.1
torchvisionVersion: 0.14.1
pytorch-cuda
torch
torchaudio
torchvision
flwr[simulation]
ray
ipywidgets
flwr["simulation"]
shap
What I Have Tried:
Uninstall and Reinstalled all libraries.
Uninstall and Reinstalled Anaconda.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there a known conflict with the versions I am using, or is there a specific step I might have missed in the setup?
Thank you in advance!

"I have created the virtual enviroment from conda." The paths in the error screenshots (which are a 'no-no' here, please read How do I ask a good question? and not the emphasized DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc) don't have conda /Anaconda in the paths and look like they were instead installed with pip? Are you sure you are in the right environment? (You should avoid mixing in pip when you choose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager or you can cause yourself headaches.)

Please fix your spelling of 'Jupyter' so knowledgeable folks can see this and assist.
